# choose 1 of 2 value when duplicate sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i wan't field ARTICLE no duplicate and DESCRIPTION choose value shortest.
I tried something but fail. Help me plz :(

```
    SELECT  
    I.ARTICLE,
    i.DESCRIPTION,
    I.TYPE,
    SUM(CASE
        When I.TYPE IN ('CONNECTOR','PROFILE') then (I.LENGTH * I.WIDTH)/1000000
        END) AS 'QTY1',
        COUNT(CASE 
        when I.TYPE IN('CONNECTOR','SPP') THEN I.ARTICLE
        END) AS 'QTY2'
FROM IDBMASTER AS I
WHERE I.ORDER_NAME IN ('2018003071') AND I.TYPE='CONNECTOR'
GROUP BY 
      I.ARTICLE,
      i.DESCRIPTION,
      I.TYPE
ORDER BY I.ARTICLE ASC;
```

THIS IS MY RESULT
RTICLE     | DESCRIPTION
012.14.920 | M5-Euro Screw 13,5 mm
017.31.639 | Hospa 3.5x15 mm
017.31.639 | Hospa 3.5x15mm
017.31.693 | Hospa 3.5x35 mm
017.31.693 | Hospa 3.5x35 mm (Without drilling hole)

Comment: Edit the question add sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: you cannot have Description in the Group By clause if you have different Descriptions for the same Article ... maybe you can use a subquery ...

Comment: Yogesh kindly edited your question so that your data was *readable* and contained in your question. Your subsequent edits have made the situation *worse*, not *better*. I'm strongly minded to rollback to version 2 - I'd rather you did that though.

Comment: i'm edited. You can see and help me

Comment: I've already given my answer which I believe should work. If it doesn't, please edit further and add more *explanation*. The sample data that Yogesh asked for would also help (we ask for sample data, we *really* want that as text not an image, so that we can copy & paste it into our query windows and give you a query that we don't just think will work but has actually been tested. For us to do that though, we need sample data and expected results)

Comment: Your conditions on `TYPE` in the `CASE` expressions are meaningless because you have filtered the rows down to a single `TYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no aggregate function for shortest, so no easy way to express this in a `GROUP BY`. So we'll use a windowed function in a subquery instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  
    I.ARTICLE,
    i.DESCRIPTION,
    I.TYPE,
    SUM(CASE
        When I.TYPE IN ('CONNECTOR','PROFILE') then (I.LENGTH * I.WIDTH)/1000000
        END) AS QTY1,
        COUNT(CASE 
        when I.TYPE IN('CONNECTOR','SPP') THEN I.ARTICLE
        END) AS QTY2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY I.ARTICLE ORDER BY LEN(I.Description) RN
FROM IDBMASTER AS I
WHERE I.ORDER_NAME IN ('2018003071') AND I.TYPE='CONNECTOR'
) T
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY I.ARTICLE ASC;
```

Here, we can use `LEN` in the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression and if two different descriptions are equally short, we'll arbitrarily select one (if you don't want arbitrary selection, add more expressions in the `ORDER BY` for the `ROW_NUMBER()`)

Comment: you can see my result and help me

Answer (score 0):

One method for solving this uses `FIRST_VALUE()`.  Unfortunately, it is not available as an aggregation function, only as a window function.

The trick is to use `SELECT DISTINCT` and to transform the rest of the aggregation functions into window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.ARTICLE,
       FIRST_VALUE(i.DESCRIPTION) OVER (PARTITION BY i.ARTICLE ORDER BY LEN(i.DESCRIPTION) as DESCRIPTION,
       I.TYPE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN I.TYPE IN ('CONNECTOR','PROFILE') THEN (I.LENGTH * I.WIDTH)/1000000
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY i.ARTICLE) AS QTY1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN I.TYPE IN( 'CONNECTOR', 'SPP')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY i.ARTICLE) AS QTY2k
FROM IDBMASTER AS I
WHERE I.ORDER_NAME IN ('2018003071') AND
      I.TYPE = 'CONNECTOR'
ORDER BY I.ARTICLE ASC;
```